# I can not find the same extension in the Open Dialog

Tags: delphi, windows-7

Why sometimes in the Open dialog I cannot load the same file extension on the Open dialog filters, so I had to refresh the first to find the file.

E.g.: `Filter = *.jpg`

I can not find the file `*.jpg` in Explorer Open dialog, but there are a lot of images with extension `*.jpg`.

This happens on Win 7 OS [x86 & x64]. The compiler version I am using is Delphi 7.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  JpgIF: TJpegImage;
  BmpIF: TBitmap;
begin
  JpgIF := TJpegImage.Create;
  BmpIF := TBitmap.Create;
  OD.FileName := '';
  OD.DefaultExt := '*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.psd;*.tga*.png;*.gif;*.bmp';
  OD.Filter := 'JPG|*.jpg|Jpeg|*.jpeg|PSD|*.psd|TGA|*.tga|PNG|*.png|GIF|*.gif|Bmp|*.bmp';
  if not OD.Execute then
    Exit
  else if LowerCase(ExtractFileExt(OD.FileName)) = '.jpg' then
  begin
    JpgIF.LoadFromFile(OD.FileName);
    Img1.Picture.Bitmap.Assign(JpgIF);
  end
  else
  begin
    if LowerCase(ExtractFileExt(OD.FileName)) = '.bmp' then
    begin
      BmpIF.LoadFromFile(OD.FileName);
      Img1.Picture.Bitmap.Assign(BmpIF);
    end;
    //etc...
  end;
  JpgIF.Free;
  BmpIF.Free;
end;
```

Comment: `else if`. `else if`.

Comment: Instead of creating all possible kinds of graphic classes, just use `Img1.Picture.LoadFromFile(OD.FileName)` which determines the appropriate graphic class automatically.

Comment: I am not familiar with your sentence structure. Could you please describe the problem in a more readable manner? I.e. What is your question?

Comment: I added support for *. psd so TImage can not do that it. This I do not know what the file on your PC through the same thing. MH : Media Fire FS : 573KB Scanned with Avira http://205.196.123.160/058dmsd4dctg/tu7y6jcbdh32obt/ZN+SAM.zip

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what your problem is.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add Jpeg, GIFImg, PngImage to uses that allows reading and writing these file types.
I have forgotten if GIFImg and PngImage is distributed with Delphi 7 so if these units are not available you need to obtain other units that provide support for the file types you want to open such as GraphicsEx.

The OpenDialog.DefaultExt contains the default extension to add to the filename if the user omits the extension when a file is saved.  Only use one extension for the defaultext property.  Only add file types to the filter that have a corresponding unit in uses unless there is a third-party unit that provides additional TGraphic filetype support in uses (GraphicEx or ImageEn for example).

```
Uses Jpeg, GIFImg, PngImage;
OD.DefaultExt := 'jpg';
// or
OD.DefaultExt := GraphicExtension(TJpegImage);
OD.Filter := 'JPG|*.jpg|Jpeg|*.jpeg|PNG|*.png|GIF|*.gif|Bmp|*.bmp';
```

If a third-party unit is used such as GraphicsEx, then you can add the units supported file types to the filter. You can download GraphicEx here: http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/all-downloads.

```
Uses GraphicEx;
```

If you use ImageEn then add ImageEnIO to uses and then register the file formats provided by ImageEnIO in OnFormCreate and unregister the file formats in OnFormDestroy:

```
Uses ImageEnIO;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { Register ImageEnIO file types to TGraphic }
  ImageEnIO.IERegisterFormats;
  OD.Filter := GraphicFilter(TGraphic);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  { UnRegister ImageENIO file types }
  IEUnRegisterFormats;
end;
```

Comment: if I add the code like this, whether it will work well?
<pre>
var
    I: Integer;
begin
    OD.Filter: = 'jpg | *. Jpg | BMP | *. Bmp';
for I: = 0 to OD.FilterIndex - 1 do
begin
case I of
    0:
    OD.DefaultExt: = '*. Jpg';
    1:
    OD.DefaultExt: = '*. Bmp';
end;

end;
<code>
  http://www.soft-gems.net/index.php/all-downloads is this free?

Comment: yes I know, it's just part of who I missed, when I type it, sorry about my english, because I use the Google translator Translator